Connect to Azure IoTHub via TMS MQTT
I'm trying to connect to Azure IoTHub via TMS MQTT in Delphi. Every time I get an error "Connection lost". I tried both methods: using a certificate and by connection string.
For instance my code to create a client with using a certificate:
FMQTTClient := TTMSMQTTClient.Create(nil);

FMQTTClient.BrokerHostName := Format('%s.azure-devices.net', \[FIoTHubHostName\]);
  FMQTTClient.BrokerPort := 443;  // also tried 8883, got "csConnectionRejected_ClientNotAuthorized"

FMQTTClient.ClientID := FMyDeviceId;

FMQTTClient.OnConnectedStatusChanged := OnConnectedStatusChanged;
  FMQTTClient.OnPublishReceived := OnMessageReceived;
  FMQTTClient.OnSSLIOHandlerConfiguration := OnSSLIOHandlerConfiguration;

FMQTTClient.KeepAliveSettings.AutoReconnect:= True;
  FMQTTClient.KeepAliveSettings.KeepAliveInterval := 30;
  FMQTTClient.KeepAliveSettings.KeepConnectionAlive := True;

FMQTTClient.Credentials.Username :=
    Format('%s.azure-devices.net/%s/?api-version=2020-09-30', \[FIoTHubHostName, FMyDeviceId\]);

// Password is not needed for client certificate authentication
  FMQTTClient.Credentials.Password := '';

if not IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load then
    raise Exception.Create('Failed to load OpenSSL');
  if not IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_2_Available then
    raise Exception.Create('TLSv1_2 is not available');

FMQTTClient.UseSSL := True;

BYW, similar client written on Python with this certificate works, so I suppose that's not a root cause.
This is the code to configure the SSL connection:
procedure TMQTTClient.OnSSLIOHandlerConfiguration(ASender: TObject;
  var ASSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL);
begin
  ASSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := FCertFileName;    // Device certificate
  ASSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := FKeyFileName;      // Device private key
  ASSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
  ASSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
end;

But every time I got "csConnectionLost" here:
procedure TMQTTClient.OnConnectedStatusChanged(ASender: TObject;
  const AConnected: Boolean; AStatus: TTMSMQTTConnectionStatus);
var
  lConnStr: string;
begin
  if AConnected {and (AStatus = csConnected)} then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Connected: True');
    if FMQTTClient.Subscribe('$iothub/methods/POST/#') > 0 then
      ShowMessage('Subscribe: Ok')
    else
      ShowMessage('Subscribe: Error');
  end
  else
    if not AConnected then
    begin
      // The client is NOT connected and any interaction with the broker will result in an exception.
      case AStatus of
        csConnectionRejected_InvalidProtocolVersion: lConnStr := 'ConnectionRejected_InvalidProtocolVersion';
        csConnectionRejected_InvalidIdentifier     : lConnStr := 'ConnectionRejected_InvalidIdentifier';
        csConnectionRejected_ServerUnavailable     : lConnStr := 'ConnectionRejected_ServerUnavailable';
        csConnectionRejected_InvalidCredentials    : lConnStr := 'ConnectionRejected_InvalidCredentials';
        csConnectionRejected_ClientNotAuthorized   : lConnStr := 'ConnectionRejected_ClientNotAuthorized'; // the connection is rejected by broker
        csConnectionLost  : lConnStr := 'ConnectionLost'; // the connection with the broker is lost
        csConnecting      : lConnStr := 'Connecting';     // The client is trying to connect to the broker
        csReconnecting    : lConnStr := 'Reconnecting';   // The client is trying to reconnect to the broker
      else
        lConnStr := 'Unknown status:' + IntToStr(Integer(AStatus));
      end;
      ShowMessage('Status: ' + lConnStr);
    end;
end;

Any thoughts, guys?
Please advise what I'm doing wrong here. Appreciate any help.

I followed this MSDOC to use MQTT to communicate with Azure IoT Hub using shared access signatures.
I also followed this GitHub repository for using the MQTT client in Delphi.
Below is the Delphi code for connecting to Azure IoT Hub via MQTT and sending the specified messages to the device.
const
  IOT_HUB_NAME      = "{iothub_name}";
  IOT_HUB_DEVICE_ID = "{device_id}";
  IOT_HUB_SAS_TOKEN = SharedAccessSignature sr=...&sig=...&se=...';
  MQTT_BROKER       = IOT_HUB_NAME + '.azure-devices.net';
  MQTT_PORT         = 8883;

var
  MQTTClient: TMQTTClient;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Messages: array[0..4] of string;
  I: Integer;
  PublishResult: Boolean;

procedure OnConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WriteLn('Connected to IoT Hub');
end;

procedure OnDisconnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WriteLn('Disconnected from IoT Hub');
end;

procedure OnPublish(Sender: TObject; const Topic: string; const Payload: string);
begin
  WriteLn('Published to topic: ' + Topic + ' with payload: ' + Payload);
end;

begin
  try
    
    MQTTClient := TMQTTClient.Create(nil);
    try
      MQTTClient.OnConnect := OnConnect;
      MQTTClient.OnDisconnect := OnDisconnect;
      MQTTClient.OnPublish := OnPublish;

    
      SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      try
        SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2; 
        SSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
        MQTTClient.IOHandler := SSL;
        MQTTClient.Username := IOT_HUB_NAME + '.azure-devices.net/' + IOT_HUB_DEVICE_ID + '/?api-version=2021-04-12';
        MQTTClient.Password := IOT_HUB_SAS_TOKEN;

        MQTTClient.Connect(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT);

        Messages[0] := 'Accio';
        Messages[1] := 'Aguamenti';
        Messages[2] := 'Alarte Ascendare';
        Messages[3] := 'Expecto Patronum';
        Messages[4] := 'Homenum Revelio';

        for I := Low(Messages) to High(Messages) do
        begin
          WriteLn('Sending message[' + IntToStr(I) + ']: ' + Messages[I]);
          PublishResult := MQTTClient.Publish('devices/' + IOT_HUB_DEVICE_ID + '/messages/events/', Messages[I]);
          if PublishResult then
            WriteLn('Message sent successfully')
          else
            WriteLn('Failed to send message');
          Sleep(1000); 
        end;

        MQTTClient.Disconnect;
      finally
        SSL.Free;
      end;
    finally
      MQTTClient.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn('Error: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end.





Output:


Thanks, Naveen for the answer.I haven't got what exactly TMQTTClient you're using in your example. Could you specify?

Sorry, in all mentioned MQTTs there's no IOHandler property in TMQTTClient class. So I don't understand line:
MQTTClient.IOHandler := SSL;
and some others.
Could you specify please the MQTT you used? Thanks.

Could you specify the exact MQTT please. Because those you mentioned in 3 links above don't work.
